# How to target specific rows of lines for the output of rpm -qi?

Tags: rhel, rpm

So if I `rpm -qi` a package it will return this:

```
Name        : testpackage
Version     : xxxxxxx
Release     : xxxxx
Architecture: xxxxxx
Install Date: xxxxxxxxxxx
Group       : xxxxxxxxxxx
Size        : xxxxxxx
License     : xxxxxxxx
Signature   : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Source RPM  : xxxxxxxxxxxx
Build Date  : xxxxxxxxxxxx
Build Host  : xxxxxxxxxxxx
Relocations : xxxxxxxx
Packager    : Red Hat, Inc. <http://xxxxxxxx>
Vendor      : Red Hat, Inc.
URL         : xxxxxxxxxx
Summary     : xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

What could I do to make the output only show the `Name`, `Packager`, and `Vendor` rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **`--queryformat`** parameter:

```
rpm -qi --queryformat "%{NAME} %{PACKAGER} %{VENDOR}\n"
```

Comment: no need for the `-i` and no need for uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, pipe it into `grep`.

```
rpm -qi packagename | grep -E '^(Name|Packager|Vendor) +:'
```